# SVG foreignObject inside symbol not showing in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I want to display HTML elements inside an SVG element using symbols.

My current attempt uses `foreignObject` to render HTML content, but it's missing in the DOM of the page when using Chrome.

I have the following code:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="hello-symbol">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
    <!-- foreignObject here -->
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" height="100" width="200">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Hello from SVG</div>
    </foreignObject>
  </symbol>
  <use href="#hello-symbol"></use>
</svg>
```

In Firefox, the code is working as expected.

In Chrome, the entire `foreignObject` node is omitted from the DOM:

```
<use href="#hello-symbol">
  #shadow-root
    <svg id="hello-symbol">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"></rect>
      <!-- foreignObject here -->
    </svg>
</use>
```

How do I get this HTML content to show up in Chrome?

Comment: You don't really. I think Firefox is likely to disallow this at some point too.

Comment: Suggest to use a floating DIV with absolute positioning outside SVG element

Comment: @RobertLongson What is the reason for that Robert?  foreignObject is still allowed in symbols per the current SVG2 draft.

Answer (score 1):

Although `<foreignObject>`s might by allowed in `<symbol>`s, they aren't in shadow trees from `<use>`. So they get filtered out when building `<use>`'s shadow tree.

[Read here for more info on why.](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/511#issuecomment-438032185)